# Dafny invalid Ident

Tags: syntax, predicate, dafny, quantifiers

I am getting an `invalid Ident` error in the `forall` line (from `is` to the first `i`), does anybody know why? This is unusual.

```
predicate SumMaxToRight(v:array<int>,i:int,s:int)
   reads v
   requires 0<=i<v.Length
  {forall l, is {:induction l} :: 0<=l<=i && is==i+1 ==> Sum(v,l,is)<=s}
```

Version 3.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `is` is a keyword in Dafny now, so it cannot be used as a variable name.

Comment: Totally, thanks! I change ```is``` with ```iss``` and it works. By the way, I answered you (will delete this) that I cannot find the bugs in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66563130/dafny-cannot-prove-function-method-equivalence-with-high-order-polymorphic-recu

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry I never got back to you. I just posted over there.